# Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'value' of type 'object' supplied to 'TextInput' React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, textinput

I have the following TextInput Component:

```
<TextInput value={this.state.inputText}
  maxLength={1}
  onSubmitEditing={this.textHandler}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({inputText: text})} />
```

When I change the input to '' and submit it (in the TextInput) I have the following error: *"Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'value' of type 'object' supplied to 'TextInput'"*

I tried deleting each callback and apparently, the error is throwed because of the 'onSubmitEditing'.

```
textHandler = (text) => {

  if(text == '' || text == '-' ){
    text = '0';
  }

  this.setState({inputText: text});
}
```

How can I make the callback to be called only where text is a string and not an object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

change your `onSubmitEditing` to

```
onSubmitEditing={(event) => this.textHandler( event.nativeEvent.text )}
```

Its a function, and you haven't passed value to it. If you want to pass you can get it from `event`

But you have used `onChangeText` which will update `inputText` so you just need to check value exists or not.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks a lot! Btw nice explanation :).

Answer (score 9):

I have faced the same issue. It normally occurs Invalid or wrong props types of the components or elements.

My case I have put in `<TextInput onChangeText={}/>` instead of `<TextInput onChange={}/>`. So I have faced the problem. Please check your props type first right or wrong. It's working for me.

Comment: To add to, if you use `onChange` instead of `onChangeText`, the e parameter passed is an event object, not the value

Comment: yeah, it usually defaults param is an event. So ?

Comment: I was using nativebase Input element and had to change to onChangeText.. the input parameter was text and worked like a charm